# How to mount/format iPod Classic that stopped being accessible after an interrupted Banshee sync?

Tags: gnome, mount, ipod, lsusb

I am running 12.04 LTS and I have an iPod classic. I had it repaired with a non-Apple store. It was at first detected by my machine running Banshee and syncing was in progress. However, due to some negligence on my part, I accidentally unplugged it while it was in progress. Now the machine will not read it and it says that the iPod is full and has no space. It will not read from a mac either.

Here is the read out from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05ac:1261 Apple, Inc. iPod Classic
```

Can I mount and format it somehow? Resetting does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reinstall firmware via iTunes under Windows/Macintosh.